# No floating points needed, but still flag type error float() in producing time series decomposition

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I self-learn time series decomposition with python. I get a float() type error.

My data source is from government open data. Basically, I want to visualize the trend of high speed rail passenger flow after the end of covid travel restriction. The time period is 2023 Jan to Nov.

The first part is data cleaning and sub-setting. The second part is time series and decomposition by month.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams

df = pd.read_csv("https://www.immd.gov.hk/opendata/eng/transport/immigration_clearance/statistics_on_daily_passenger_traffic.csv")

# data cleaning
df = df.iloc[: , :-1]
df = df[df["Date"].str.contains("2023") == True]

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%d-%m-%Y"))

control_point = df['Control Point'].tolist()

options = ['Airport', 'Express Rail Link West Kowloon', 'Lo Wu', 'Lok Ma Chau Spur Line', 'Heung Yuen Wai', 'Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macao Bridge', 'Shenzhen Bay']

df_clean = df.loc[df['Control Point'].isin(options)] 

df_XRL = df[df["Control Point"].str.contains("Express Rail Link West Kowloon") & df["Arrival / Departure"].str.contains("Departure")]
df_XRL = df_XRL[["Date","Hong Kong Residents"]]
df_XRL = df_XRL[~(df_XRL['Date'] > '2023-11-30')]
df_XRL['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_XRL['Date']).strftime("%b")
df_XRL['Week day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_XRL['Date']).strftime("%a")

# Pivot table

from numpy import nan
monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov']
dayOrder = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

pivot_XRL = pd.pivot_table(df_XRL, index=['Month'],
                        values=['Hong Kong Residents'],
                        columns=['Week day'], aggfunc=('sum')).loc[monthOrder, (slice(None), dayOrder)]

# Time Series Decomposition - where errors occur

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_XRL, model = "additive")
decomposition.plot()
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 16
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6628\3049465439.py in <module>
      1 from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
----> 2 decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_XRL, model = "additive")
      3 decomposition.plot()
      4 plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
      5 plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 16

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, period, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    140         pfreq = getattr(getattr(x, "index", None), "inferred_freq", None)
    141 
--> 142     x = array_like(x, "x", maxdim=2)
    143     nobs = len(x)
    144 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\validation\validation.py in array_like(obj, name, dtype, ndim, maxdim, shape, order, contiguous, optional)
    133     if optional and obj is None:
    134         return None
--> 135     arr = np.asarray(obj, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    136     if maxdim is not None:
    137         if arr.ndim > maxdim:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   2082     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
   2083         values = self._values
-> 2084         arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   2085         if (
   2086             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. This issue is I haven't set the date as index. After adding the script: `df_XRL = df_XRL.set_index('Date')`, I can plot the graph.